# How to disable the yellow lightbulb suggested action menu?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

How do I disable this yellow lightbulb suggestion menu? I find it distracting and don't use it often. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio Code , you can disable the yellow lightbulb suggestion menu.

1. Open VS Code.
2. Click on the "File" menu in the top-left corner and select "Preferences."
3. From the dropdown menu that appears, select "Settings."
4. In the "Settings" tab, you can search for specific settings related to suggestions or code hints by typing in the search bar. For example, you can search for "editor.suggest" or "editor.parameterHints" to find related settings.
5. Look for the setting that controls code suggestions or hints and toggle it off. This might be something like "Editor: Parameter Hints" or "Editor: Suggest." You can click on the setting to change its value to "false" or uncheck a checkbox if available.
6. Make sure to save your settings by clicking the disk icon in the top-right corner or pressing `Ctrl` + `S` (or `Cmd` + `S` on macOS).

This should disable the yellow lightbulb suggestion menu in VS Code.